# Как вызвать справку jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Каким сочетанием клавиш можно вызвать справку по вводимой функции в jupyter notebook?
Так, что-бы справка выводилась по ходу ввода функции...

Comment: `function_name?` нажать `Ctrl+Enter`. Чтобы посмотреть исходный код - `function_name??` нажать `Ctrl+Enter`

Comment: @MaxU, мне кажется вопрос скорее о том, чтобы во всплывающей подсказке в процессе ввода видеть "прототип" функции, ее принимаемые параметры, например. Мне, кстати тоже интересно)

Comment: @insolor, можно набрать имя функции, модуля и нажать `Shift+Tab`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно введя имя функции или модуля нажать `Shift+Tab`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

окно подсказки можно увеличить нажав на `+` в верхнем правом углу окна подсказки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста как сделать подсказку методов класса, когда пишешь класс выпадает сразу список всех методов